# For loop stops after one output

Tags: python

Make an integer of product, multiplier and multiplicand

```
def fac(n) :
  f = []
  for i in range(2,int(n/2)) :
    if n % i == 0 : f.append(i)
  return f
def check(n) :
  g = []
  for j in fac(n) :
    g.append(n)
    g.append(j)
    g.append(int(n/j))
    x = int("".join(map(str, g)))
    return x
print (check(28))
```

gives output 28214 which is expected but it gives only one output stops after that
why doesn't return next 2847(28,4,7) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You need to simply change the return in check function to `yield` thereby converting it to a generator and we can use the `next` function to iterate through the output

```
def fac(n) :
  f = []
  for i in range(2,int(n/2)) :
    if n % i == 0 : f.append(i)
  return f

def check(n) : 
  for j in fac(n) :
    g=[]
    g.append(n)
    g.append(j)
    g.append(int(n/j))
    x = int("".join(map(str, g)))
    yield x
print("using for loop")
#print (check(28))
for i in check(28):
    print(i)


print("Using next function")
n=check(28)
print(next(n))
print(next(n))
print(next(n))
```

OUTPUT

```
using for loop
28214
2847
2874
Using next function
28214
2847
2874
```

Comment: @anon-bee-01 Did you copy my code ? or Just changed the return to yield

Comment: You need to make the g in check function inside the for loop

Comment: Yes I didnt notice the g inside loop. Now I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Return exits the function, which exits the loop. You could try printing x in the loop or build up and then return x outside of the loop.

Comment: when returned outside of loop gives 2821428472874 which contains next outputs how do I separate them ?

Comment: You could create a list and keep appending results to it and then return the list outside the loop

Comment: creating list inside loop did the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in fac(n) :
    g.append(n)
    g.append(j)
    g.append(int(n/j))
    x = int("".join(map(str, g)))
    return x
```

The `return x` is aligned with the iterator; if you want it to return multiple values, you'd want to move it to the left so that it aligns with the `for j` loop.

I also think you want to return list g as opposed to x.